# Bigquery load_table_from_file not loading table table,having size of 90 Mb?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am trying to read data from api and try to save it to a file.
The file is saved as NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON.
Then I am using load_table_from_file method to load to bigquery.

But,for a particular month,the rows are 16180 and file size is around 90  MB.

For that month,the rows are not getting loaded.
and ,I am not getting any errors also.
Below is my code,which I am using to load data.

For other months,I am able to load the data.

```py
    client = bigquery.Client('ncau-data-newsquery-sit')
    dataset_id = 'test_dataset'
    table_id = 'table'
    dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
    job_config.autodetect = True
    
    with open(tempFile, "rb") as source_file:
    
          try:
            job = client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_ref, job_config=job_config)   
          except Exception:
            pass
    job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.
    print("Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.".format(job.output_rows, dataset_id, table_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't saw a such of limitation in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#limitations) when loading `Json` `GCS` file to `BigQuery`.

A limitation is indicated for `gzip` file, the maxium size for a file is 4 GB.

Also for big files, it's better using compressed file as `gzip` because the loading to `BigQuery` is faster.